# T-SQL pivot where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

in SQL Server i want PIVOT a table and add a WHERE clause but i cant figure out the syntax.

## The data

> ```
> dbo.SOME_VIEW
> YEAR  AMOUNT
> ====================
> 2014  1
> 2013  2
> 2012  5.6
> 2011  574
> 2010  123
> ```

## The Query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM SOME_VIEW
PIVOT (SUM(AMOUNT) FOR [YEAR] IN ([2012], [2013], [2014])) AS PIVOTED
```

Now i want to get from the view only the row with the year that i will PIVOT so i want to add

`WHERE YEAR IN (2012, 2013, 2014)`

## What i have tried

Put `WHERE` after `FROM SOME_VIEW`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM SOME_VIEW WHERE YEAR IN (2012, 2013, 2014)
PIVOT (SUM(AMOUNT) FOR [YEAR] IN ([2012], [2013], [2014])) AS PIVOTED
```

i get: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'`. When i add the `WHERE` at the end end i get `Invalid column name 'YEAR'`.

## Question

Where can i add the WHERE clause when i use PIVOT?

## Why

For performance. In the view i have years from 1990 but i want only the last thre years. I expect when i add a where i improve performance.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Any rows with `pivot_column` values not mentioned in the `IN` clause are automatically excluded by the `PIVOT` operation itself.

Comment: **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/434756)** With current requirements there is no need for `WHERE` at all.

Comment: i asked because i thought a explicit WHERE clause would  improve performance. So does the PIVOT an implicit WHERE?

Comment: Not as such. There's just no-where for the data from those other rows to *go*. And in SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. Don't try adding things "for performance".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever put this as an answer - i will accept it.

Answer (score 9):

As I understand it you want to restrict the years that are passed on to the PIVOT.

You can do this by using a Common Table Expression.

This should work for you:

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT
 *
FROM #SOME_VIEW 
WHERE [YEAR] IN (2012, 2013, 2014))

SELECT
 *
FROM CTE
PIVOT (SUM(AMOUNT) FOR [YEAR] IN ([2012], [2013], [2014])) AS PIVOTED
```

RESULTS:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I know exactly where is your problem, since I am jut facing it right now.
The WHERE Clause and the PIVOT Clause don't like each other. So, PIVOT cannot come Directly after WHERE, unless there is a barrier between them.
This say, you **MUST wrap your SELECT Clause as a Subquery of another SELECT Clause,** like this:

SELECT * FROM

(

SELECT
*
FROM SOME_VIEW
WHERE YEAR IN (2012, 2013, 2014)

)

PIVOT (SUM(AMOUNT) FOR [YEAR] IN ([2012], [2013], [2014])) AS PIVOTED

**WITH COMMENTS**

SELECT * FROM **--Master Query you should add**

(

SELECT * **-- This is the query you had before**

FROM SOME_VIEW

WHERE YEAR IN (2012, 2013, 2014)

) **-- End of the Master Query. This is the barrier between the WHERE and the PIVOT. After this parenthesis, you can now safely call you PIVOT Clause.**

PIVOT (SUM(AMOUNT) FOR [YEAR] IN ([2012], [2013], [2014])) AS PIVOTED